# Using a GoogleSpreadsheet to fill in a PDF form

Tags: pdf, google-sheets, pdf-form

I have a very specific question and I would be extremely happy if anybody has any guess on how to solve it. I have: 1.- a PDF form which I have not created myself. 2.- a GoogleSpreadsheet created by myself.

Now the question is: is there any way I can fill in the PDF form using the information in the GoogleSpreadsheet, taking into account that this process should be activated from the GoogleSpreadsheet (since the PDF form is not mine)?

Best regards and thanks so much for everyone's input!

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

You would need edit access to the PDF form, in order to get the field names. With that information, you could create a FDF (Forms Data Format, a PDF-related file format for data, using PDF syntax) file from the Google spreadsheet, which does refer to the PDF form as a base PDF. You then could open that FDF from the spreadsheet, and it should, if your webbrowser supports the Acrobat browser plug-in, grab the base PDF and populate it.

If you can not get the opening from the spreadsheet to work, download the FDF file and open it in Acrobat/Reader, or open the base form in Acrobat/Reader and import the data from the FDF file.